# Xperia Z2: where are "Developer options", eclipse cannot see tablet.

Tags: usb, settings, sony-xperia

My eclipse (Android's ADT download, on Windows 7) did not see my new Sony Xperia Z2 tablet when connected by USB.

I downloaded the driver to the PC but didn't install it (long story), and switched the Xperia's USB connection to Mass Storage Mode (as recommended in other posts).

I couldn't find the "Developer Options" in the Xperia's Settings.

Answer (score 3):

There is a magic trick! It's in this post "http://www.androidpolice.com/2012/11/13/reminder-tip-developer-options-are-hidden-in-android-4-2-heres-how-to-find-them/". In brief, Settings --> About tablet --> has "Build number" at bottom. Tap on this many times, and you'll get a pop-up saying (something I didn't catch), and the Developer Options now appear as Settings --> About tablet --> Developer Options. You may want to turn on USB Debugging.

Mega-Grumble!!

Answer (score 1):

Old post i know but, try this.

http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/drivers/

You should be using Android Studio now though far better in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Go to about phone and click on Build number 7 times.
In this way you can enable actual developer settings.
I hope this would help you.